# Escape sequences with String Interpolation

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Using C# 6 I have the following:

```
$"\{wordSeparator}+"
```

This does not compile because of \ so I tried:

```
$"\\{wordSeparator}+"
```

This compiles but when I ran my code I got the error:

```
Unrecognized escape sequence \\
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that message from and can you include the entire exception and stack trace and the value of `wordSeparator`?

Answer (score 1):

"wordseparator" is supposed to be a variable. This works:

```
string wordSeparator = "\\";
string s = $"\\{wordSeparator}+";
```

If "wordseparator" is not a variable but part of the string you should escape the '{' as well:

```
string s = $"\\{{wordSeparator}}+";
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message from your first example:

> CS8087: A '{' character may only be escaped by doubling '{{' in an interpolated string.

Comment: Sorry, but I am trying to escape the \ ... { } is String interpolation in C# 6, e.g: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx

Comment: @MiguelMoura: Then your second example works fine; what's the problem?  http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/f:>ilr/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayUAJ0iwA7n3mC4qXFXlVkamAF4YAIhM5Zsnjph1jAEhMAdJ01XrN23fvkBfANTmMmy+2L5AA===